# How this problem can be defined as MultiObjective optimisation

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, integer-programming, scheduling, multi-objective-optimization

I need to optimize the end-to-end latency of a multi-component application.

Assuming that the application has 10 components, component 1-5 is hosted by device 1, and device 2 is hosting the other 5 components. Note device 1 has cpu limitation and device 2 has unlimited cpu.

The end-to-end latency is calculated by the execution time of 1-5 component + the output data transfer time of component 5 ( to be fed as input to the component 6 (on device 2)) + the execution time of component 6-10.

Due to some system load on device 1, the allocation needs to be changed for instance component 1-3 on device 1 and component 4-10 on device 2 but this allocation must consider the bandwidth constraint and cpu limitation of device1.

I would like to ask can this problem be considered multiobjective or not?.I need to use a multiobjective algorithm to solve the below problem such as pareto optimality or genetic algorithm. The end to end latency is affected by the bandwidth (bandwidth constraint) and device 1 cpu limitation (device1 constraint).

Help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you thougth to introduce 20 binary variables and write an Integer Linear Porgramm model?
$ x_{i,j} $ could be a Boolean variable whose value is 1 if i-th component is assigned to j-th training device,  0 otherwise where $i=1,2, \cdots, 10 $ and $i=1,2$.

Comment: @marcotognoli thank you very much for your response. Would you please elaborate more on modeling this problem as a linear programming model. Thanks

Comment: I have just written the more general model. As you can see it is not necessary to consider a multiobjective model because you can easily consider only one single objective function.

Answer (score 2):

**Model without bandwidth limitation**

We wish to select the most performing components to be hosted by two devices in order to have an end-to-end latency as minimum as possible.

Let $ x_{i,j} $ be a Boolean variable whose value is 1 if i-th component is assigned to j-th device,  0 otherwise where $i=1,2, \cdots, 10 $ and $i=1,2$. The **cpu limitation** (equals to $c_1$) constraint could be written as

$ \sum_{i=1}^{10} x_{i,1} \leq c_1 $

In order to allocate every component only in 1 and only 1 device and not have a trivial solution (i.e. all variables equal to zero), we can impose that

$ \sum_{j=1}^2 x_{i,j} = 1 $ for every $i=1,\cdots , 10$

The following constraint

$ \sum_{i=1}^{10} x_{i,1} \geq 1 $

requires that at least one component is hosted by device 1 and

$ \sum_{i=1}^{10} x_{i,2} \geq 1 $

the same for device 2.

Let $t_i$ be the execution time of components and $T_i$ the output data transfer time of component i from 1st device to 2nd device. The **obijective function** Z to be minimized could be

> $ Z = ( \sum_{j=1}^2 \sum_{i=1}^{10} t_i  \cdot x_{i,j} ) + T $

where $T$ should designate the *output data transfer time* of i-th component in last position on board of device 1. Because we do not consider bandwidth limitation, $T$ will be equal to 0.

**Model with bandwidth limitation**

Let $b_i$ be the bandwidth of every components, we have to consider the **bandwidth contraint** applied only on the “last” component on board of 1st device. This point requires to consider auxiliary variables indicating the ranking of the components on board of device 1 and furnishing the output data transfer time $T$.
Because the output data transfer time $T$ is inversely proportional to $b_i$, as last component on device 1 we wish to select the largest available bandwidth.
Let introduce ten Boolean auxiliary variables, $ z_1, \cdots, z_{10} $, assuming value is 1 if i-th component transmits bytes from device 1 to device 2.
Because only one component is designate to transmit from device 1 to device 2, we introduce the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^{10} z_i = 1$.

$ \min T $

$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
T \geq \sum_{i=1}^{10} b^{-1}_i \cdot z_i \\
x_{1,2} + z_1 \leq 1 \\
x_{2,2} + z_2 \leq 1  \\
\vdots \\
x_{10,2} + z_{10} \leq 1 \\
\sum_{i=1}^{10} z_i = 1 \\
T \geq 0 \\
z_1, \cdots, z_{10} binary \\
\end{array} \right. $

The logic constraint $x_{i,2} + z_i \leq 1$ guarantees to avoid to select components that are allocated on device 2: $x_{i,2}=1 \implies z_i=0$.

Finally, the model is:

> $ Z = ( \sum_{j=1}^2 \sum_{i=1}^{10} t_i  \cdot x_{i,j} ) + T $

s.t.

> $\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
> T \geq \sum_{i=1}^{10} b^{-1}_i \cdot z_i \\
> \sum_{i=1}^{10} x_{i,1} \leq c_1 \\
> \sum_{j=1}^2 x_{1,j} = 1 \\
> \vdots \\
> \sum_{j=1}^2 x_{10,j} = 1 \\
> \sum_{i=1}^{10} x_{i,1} \geq 1 \\
> \sum_{i=1}^{10} x_{i,2} \geq 1 \\
> x_{1,2} + z_1 \leq 1 \\
> x_{2,2} + z_2 \leq 1  \\
> \vdots \\
> x_{10,2} + z_{10} \leq 1 \\
> \sum_{i=1}^{10} z_i = 1 \\
> T \geq 0 \\
> z_1, \cdots, z_{10},x_{1,1}, \cdots, x_{2,10}  binary \\
> \end{array} \right. $

Answer (score 2):

You can treat it as multiobjective if you treat end-to-end latency as one objective (to be minimized) and load on device 1 (which has limited capacity) as another objective (also to be minimized).